# Angular 2 (cli) protractor jasmine expect is not resolving promise

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I am writing E2E tests with Protractor and Angular 2 using Jasmine.

I am trying to do a simple expectation on the `getText()` of an element returned by protractor.

```
it('should display correct hero title', () => {
    expect(element(by.css('Hero-title')).getText()).toEqual('Foobar');
});
```

This results in a **type** error:

```
Argument of type '"Foobar"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Expected<Promise<string>>'. [2345]
```

I know I could use `.then` but I don't want to do that as I will have loads of these types of expectations.

Using a fresh Angular CLI project this works as expected. I have gone through all the configs but cannot find any differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This relates to `jasmine`, starting with 2.5.46, *enforcing correct typings*, here is a related open issue in the Protractor issue tracker:

- [Typings issue since @types/jasmine update](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4176)

As a workaround, you can pin your "jasmine types" version to 2.5.45 until the issue is fixed:

```
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.45"
```